# Trouble calling C# 32 bit Com from 64 bit C# application

Tags: c#, .net, dll, com

First thing, I know there are several articles about doing what I want to do. It is nothing special. But I have read numerous articles here and elsewhere and read multiple examples and I seem to get conflicting information as well as very mediocre success. I am asking people familiar with COM to be patient and help somebody who is just getting into COM for the first time.

I will explain what I believe to be what needs done based on my research and ask knowledgeable people to point out what I am doing wrong and help me fill in the knowledge gaps. My application uses third party 32-bit DLLs and 64-bit DLLs. There are a bunch of the 64-bit and only one 32-bit. This is why I am using a 64-bit application. If anyone cares, it is the Minolta kmsecs200.dll. The web site is clear that they do not have a 64 bit version.

The first step is to create the 32 bit COM wrapper. At this point, my sample code does not wrap anything. It just has one simple function. Here are the steps I took to create the DLL:

Create a new C#, windows, class Library (.Net Framework), .NET Framework 4

Name the project “SimpleCom”, rename the class and CS file to “JustOne”

In the project properties:
On Application Tab: Click "Assembly Information" and set “Make assembly COM-Visible”
On Build tab: Set Platform target to x86
On Signing tab: Select "Sign the assembly" and create a new Strong Name Key file named "StrongSimpleCom", no password protection

This is the JustOne.cs code:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace SimpleCom
{
  [Guid("EAA4976A-45C3-4BC5-BC0B-E47474C3C83F")]
  public interface IJustOne
  {
    [DispId(1)]
    string AddName(string name);
  }

  [Guid("0D53A3E8-E51A-49C7-BC0B-E47474C3C83F"),
      ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
  public class JustOne : IJustOne
  {
    public JustOne() { }

    public string AddName(string name)
    { return "My name is: " + name; }

  }
}
```

---

Register the 32-bit Assembly on the target machine:
From an administrative command prompt, navigate to the DLL folder
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe SimpleCom.dll /codebase /tlb:myTlb.tlb
I used /codebase because I do not yet know how to call the third party DLL if I put my DLL in GAC. I do not really understand what the tlb file is for once registered. I would like to know if someone can tell me.
At this point, the COM object shows up in Visual Studio but I can not call it that way and I understand that. It just tells me it is registered at least in some sense of the word.
So I think I should be able to Invoke the 32 bit C# DLL that I wrote from a 32 bit C# application. But I just can not figure out how to do it. I can't seem to even find a good example of using invoke. I would really appreciate help on how to invoke "IJustOne" in a simple application.

Once that works, I can add some registry entries to make it out of process and make the 32 bit application into a 64 bit application. Here is one of the ways I have heard to modify the registry to make the 32 bit COM oup of process and use the DLLhost as the surrogate.

***Techtalk.gfi.com method from 2009****
Navigate to: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WOW6432Node\CLSID{EAA4976A….}
•   Add “AppID” with value set to Guid
Navigate to: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WOW6432Node\AppID
•   Create a new key using the Guid as the name
•   In the key, Add “DllSurrogate” with no value
Navigate to: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID
•   Create a new key using the Guid as the name

Again I am having trouble finding good straight forward examples of how to invoke the COM object. I have created a C# DLL wrapper that I can directly include in a simple C# 32 bit application so I am comfortable with wrapping the unmanaged 3rd party DLL. I would like to know how to ensure my wrapper DLL can find their DLL.

I do not know what I am doing wrong with registering the DLL and I do not know how to invoke it in a 64 bit application, or a 32 bit for that matter. I appreciate any assistance. I have spent several days trying to chase this down but in the end, my knowledge base is just not strong enough. But a recap of the big picture:
I am using 3rd part 32 bit unmanaged DLL. I need to call it from my 64 bit C# application. I believe the way to do it is wrap it in a managed C# 32 bit DLL wrapper and make it an out of process COM object the uses DLLhost as the surrogate.

Thanks again,

Dave

Comment: Do you really have to use COM also between your 64bit app and the 32bit Helper process? It might be simpler to use some other RPC mechanism instead.

Comment: Instead of "manual" surrogate, I suggest you use Component Services it's easier to setup and has more features. Here's an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52601470/calling-function-from-64bit-app-from-a-32bit-dll/52601719 although the dll is in C++, it's exactly the same principle (note this is all programmable beyond UI to automate a setup). Otherwise: 1) you don't need the GAC which can be a pain, just /codebase 2) TLB defines your object metadata, for any COM client that would like to use your object (.NET, C++, Delphi, Scripts,etc.) or for Component Services registration

Comment: I am not married to COM at all. While searching for information on Microsoft web site I came across this which says to use COM:   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/process-interoperability       But I am willing to do it a different way if this is not the best way. I will look at the link provided by Simon and see what I can find. Thank You.

Comment: Klaus Gutter, If you have a better suggestion than COM, I am absolutely interested in hearing it. Do you have a suggestion and a link that can show me an alternate way?

Comment: Simon, Following the instructions for the sample code link you provided, I did run the COM+ application and created a new application and added my component. Since I had called regasm on my wrapper DLL earlier, my component was in the list. When I created a new C# application and went to add a COM object, it said a reference to "SimpleCom" could not be added. The ActiveX type library was exported from a .NET assembly and I should add it as a .NET assembly. But it is not in the Assemblies list. Do I need to do this differently because my wrapper DLL it is a .NET DLL?

Comment: You can't add a reference to a .NET COM object from a .NET client "as a COM object". Reference it normally (also compile it as Any CPU, it's always better). If you want a quick test, don't reference anything, just use the C# dynamic keyword as in the end of my answer.

Comment: Thank you Simon, I did overlook that detail. And the good new is that it worked!! That is the first time in two weeks that I have been able to call my function. Ideally, I would be able to use the same IJustOne interface and do a typecast but at least I have fucntionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simon pointed me in the right direction above. My DLL was registered just fine. I added it as a component through component services and everything worked after that. Thank You Simon.