VBA Excel Macro now on 64 bit Excel new issue with one of the object reference library
I have a VBA Macro I created years ago that connects to Avaya CMS Supervisor via Object library components to run some reports, paste them into excel then it creates a combined report and some unique calacutions.
When we switched to 64 Bit Excel last month, the Macro broke first with needing the PtrSafe Declaration. Fixed those but now when I attempt to run the macro it is failing with an error

Old Format or Invalid Type Library


The only info I found on that message was from years ago with issues when the file system and excel had different region settings. I am wondering if it is because the EXE it is requesting from the object library is 32 bit. There is not a 64 bit version.
Any ideas on some troubleshooting ideas for this? Running on empty to try to solve it.
Researched different variable types and differences between 32 bit and 64 bit VBA Code

You can't talk from a 64bit app to a 32bit COM component (or the reverse) which exists as a DLL, it's called an "in-process" component. The only solution for 64-32 communication is to use a COM component as an .exe (and "out-of-process" component). You can host an existing .dll or rewrite it. For example https://stackoverflow.com/a/52602821/403671
